# First order condition of sum of squares with respect to variance of residuals

Tags: mathematical-statistics, least-squares, residuals, sums-of-squares

Consider the criterion function for ordinary least squares 
$$
S(b)=(Y-X'b)'(Y-X'b)
$$
with Y, a matrix of dependent variables, and X, a matrix of explanatory variables. It is of course known that: 
$$
\frac{\partial S}{\partial \beta} = -2\cdot X'Y+2\cdot X'X\cdot b
$$
solving for $b$ yields the OLS estimator for $b$.

Now if we think of $\sigma^2$, the variance of the residuals, as a parameter to be estimated does it then make sense to
$$
\frac{\partial S}{\partial \sigma^2} ?
$$
if so what is it?

Answer (score 1):

As usually $Y\sim \mathcal{N}(X'b,\sigma^2 I_n)$, you can write $$S(b)=S(b,\sigma)=(Y-X'b)'(Y-X'b)=\epsilon'\epsilon$$ with the vector of residuals $\epsilon \sim \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2 I_n)$ and their standardized version $\sigma^{-1}\epsilon=\epsilon_0 \sim \mathcal{N}(0,I_n)$.

So $$\frac{\partial S}{\partial \sigma^2}=(Y-X'b)'(Y-X'b)=\frac{\epsilon'\epsilon}{\sigma^2}={\epsilon_0}'\epsilon_0.$$

Note by the way that $$E(\frac{\epsilon'\epsilon}{\sigma^2})=E({\epsilon_0}'\epsilon_0)=n,$$ where $n$ is the length of $Y$ or $\epsilon$. This result holds even if the residuals are not Gaussian but at least centered and their variance is parametrized by $\sigma^2$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply! Do you mean that the derivative is $(Y_0-X'b)'(Y_0-X'b)$ if so how would I estimate that from the data?

Comment: I might have been unclear, but I am pretty sure that what you call $\sigma$ is what I would like to have the derivative with respect to.

Comment: Corrected. As $S$ is a random variable, you cannot estimate it. But I added the expectation.

Comment: But if I want to have an estimate for $\frac{\partial S}{\partial \sigma^2}$ i would estimate it just by $\epsilon ' \epsilon / \sigma_e^2$ (where $\epsilon$ are observed residuals) and $\sigma_e^2$ is my estimate of residual variance right? and If I where to estimate $\frac{\partial^2 S}{\partial \sigma^2}$ it would just be estimated by $\epsilon ' \epsilon$? Is the mixed derivatives, i.e.  $\frac{\partial^2 S}{\partial \sigma^2 \partial \beta}$ possible to estimate? Thanks so much for your help so far, if you can help me with this last issue I would be really grateful.

Comment: $\frac{\partial S}{\partial \sigma^2}$ is also a random variable. You don't estimate it, you observe it. In turn, $\frac{\epsilon'\epsilon}{\sigma^2_{\epsilon}}$ is known. It is $\frac{1}{N-r(X)}$, where $r(X)$ denotes the rank of $X$.

Comment: Okay, I see. Is the second derivative and mixed derivative i mentioned above also expressable by data? Do you have a reference where I can find this kind of stuff? -I have been googling like a mad man, but it seems people always only do the basic stuff about OLS.

Comment: Ah.. From what you wrote the second and mixed derivatives are all 0, right? That expression there is though still somewhat remarkable.

Comment: The arithmetic on the first line is incorrect: when you divide $Y$ by $\sigma$ you must also divide $X^\prime b$ by $\sigma$, too. A different approach is needed to address this question, which implicitly is looking at the problem from a maximum likelihood point of view. Writing the likelihood for this model will provide a useful point of departure.

Comment: Hi whuber. Thank you very much for replying, is there anywhere I can read this stuff? I know it is really impolite, but I am really in a pickle of time and horrible at statistics so it would most likely take me very long time to figure it out.

Comment: @whuber: True, I think I've fixed it. Still, $S$ is the squared euclidean length of the residuals. $\sigma$ does nothing than rescaling that length so the rest was right. What I confused was that if you change $\sigma$ in the model, you do not change the expectation.

Comment: Although what you have rewritten makes intuitive sense, Horst, from a mathematical standpoint it's going to take a lot of explanation: after all, $S$ is a *random variable* (not a real-valued function) whose underlying distribution is parameterized by $\sigma$. Thus you need to invoke a generalization of Calculus in which differentiating such objects makes sense and you will need to show it satisfies the usual rules. Unless you like that sort of mathematical research, you will find it easier to approach this question *via* the likelihood, which *is* a real-valued function of $b$ and $\sigma$.

Comment: This question _is_ about the random variables, not the likelihood functions. The random variables here are parametrized mappings from a probability space $\Omega$. The parameter of interest is $\sigma$. The results can be considered as if a $\omega \in \Omega$ would have been fixed. Likelihood is not another approach to that question, it is another question. However, I admit that all the confusion about estimating a rv and treating a rv as a parameter is a hint that another question might have been intended.

Comment: If you insist on viewing $S$ in your equations as a measurable real-valued function on an abstract probability space--which is correct but problematic for what you are trying to do--then you will run into even more trouble making sense of its derivative with respect to $\sigma$. (Recall that derivatives are limits of difference quotients: what quotient do you have in mind and how will you define the limit?) I am suggesting likelihood *is* a useful approach due to the intimate connection between the MLE (with Gaussian residuals) and the OLS solution.

Comment: Hi whuber. I think you helped me solve my problem, thank you very, very much!